# Counting Decimal Values

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am trying to count the total cells that have a single decimal value.

**For example:**

```
1.1 (1)
2
1.2 (2)
3.333
1.3 (3)
4
1.4 (4)
5.55555
1.5 (5)
6
1.6 (6)
1.7777777
1.7 (7)
8
1.8 (8)
9.999999999
1.9 (9)
```

What formula should be used to attain a total of nine?

Comment: Have you tried the given solutions? Did any work for you? If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(LEN(INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A,"."),,2)),"=1"))
```

[image: COUNTIF only one decimal digit in range]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)
- [`LEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081)
- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)

Comment: You can reduce that to  `=COUNTIF(A2:A,"*.*")`

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I believe the OP used the `(1)` etc. as a guide to just show which values to count.